# Issue with intercepting manually encrypted Keycloak token in the Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm having issue with intercepting token that needs to be decrypted before any action has been taken in the controller:

I have security configs like this with filter registraton before KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter:

`protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { super.configure(http); http.addFilterBefore(new TokenInterceptorFilter(tokenDecryptor), KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.class); }`

My class is implementing Filter:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenInterceptorFilter.class);

private TokenDecryptor tokenDecryptor;

public TokenInterceptorFilter(TokenDecryptor tokenDecryptor){
    this.tokenDecryptor= tokenDecryptor;
}
public String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames( );
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements( )) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement( );
        log.info("Header Name: " + headerName + " " + request.getHeader(headerName));
    }
    return request.getHeader("authorization");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String oldToken = extractToken((HttpServletRequest) request);
    String newToken = "";
    if (oldToken != null && !oldToken.startsWith("Bearer ey")) {
        newToken = tokenDecryptor.splitAndDecryptToken(oldToken);
        CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        wrappedRequest.addHeader("authorization",  "Bearer " + newToken);
        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
        extractToken(wrappedRequest);
    } else
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

But my error is 401 when I put encrypted token in authorization header, and TomcatEmbeddedContext gives me /error page.

Is there any other option to intercept filter like this one?

Thanks...

I tried to change filer ordering, and tried using OncePerRequestFilter, but nothing worked...

Comment: 1. Show us an example token or log it
2. Are you sure the header doesnt start with "Authorization" (capital A)?